# CMake problems with CLion - Error:Cannot determine link language for target "XYZ"

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

Starting up CLion  outputs me the following:

```
Error:Cannot find source file:
  sinclude/MathCompiler.h
Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .m .M .mm .h .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx
Error:CMake can not determine linker language for target: MathCompiler
Error:Cannot determine link language for target "MathCompiler".
Warning:Configuration Debug
Unable to determine product file path for target MathCompiler (Debug). Running and debugging will be unavailable.
Warning:Configuration Release
Unable to determine product file path for target MathCompiler (Release). Running and debugging will be unavailable.
Warning:Configuration RelWithDebInfo
Unable to determine product file path for target MathCompiler (RelWithDebInfo). Running and debugging will be unavailable.
Warning:Configuration MinSizeRel
Unable to determine product file path for target MathCompiler (MinSizeRel). Running and debugging will be unavailable.
```

I didn't change anything since the last build.

Here is CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(MathCompiler)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp cpp/MathCompiler.cpp include/MathCompiler.h cpp/MathException.cpp include/MathException.h cpp/MathematicString.cpp include/MathematicString.h include/str_cmp.h include/typedefs.h)
add_executable(MathCompiler ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: The strange part is the `s` in `sinclude` of `Error:Cannot find source file: sinclude/MathCompiler.h`. Please double check you `CMakeLists.txt`. Generally the message just says that it couldn't find the file and therefore couldn't determine its programming language.

Comment: `.h`-files usually aren't included into the list of source files

Comment: Please add your comment as answer. Then i can accept it. It solved my problem perfectly. Thank you @user3159253

Comment: @C3D1 could you please share what you did that solved the problem? Running into similar issue, but the hint is too cryptic for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.h-files usually aren't included into the list of source files

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Well, if you haven't noticed, this answer simply duplicates my own comment above which has helped the author to resolve his problem. The comment was turned into the answer upon author's request. So, I guess, sapienti sat

Comment: But certainly, if you have an idea how to improve the answer, you could propose an edit. Most likely I won't mind.